# Jackson NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory

Tags: java, maven, jackson, yaml

I am trying to read a yaml file from a java class, but I have two problems. The first is that in my yaml file, I have a list of objects of an abstract class, and I am not sure of what to do about it. Is it possible to read this as a default object and then get the properties with something like `obj.get("my-propertie")`so that I can reconstruct the object afterward with the correct subclass ? Here is a sample of my yaml. The overall is represented by an `Equipment` class, and each element belongs to an abstract `Invocable` class, of which Jetpack is a subclass.

```
unblocked:
  main_hand: []
  helmet: []
  boots: []
  Chestplate:
  - className: Jetpack
    fuel: 120
    color: RED
  offhand: []
  leggings: []
invoked:
  main_hand: null
  chestplate: null
  helmet: null
  boots: null
  offhand: null
  leggings: null
```

The second problem is that I get this error when running my code :
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory`, but I don't use JsonFactory anywhere, and the stack trace does not seem relevant. I have this error even with a simple yaml file. Here are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks for any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the JsonFactory under the hood as an indirect dependency. Maven should normally add such dependencies automatically but it often does not due to wrong configuration (on their server side and in the libs).

In case of YAML parsing I know for sure that dependencies are missing. I had the same issue some few weeks ago.